# Test Failed: 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python

This is the error I'm getting: 
Test Failed: 'type' object is not iterable

This is my code:

```
import math

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def std_dev(persons):
    persons=Person
    mean = sum(persons)*1.0/len(persons)
    length = len(persons)
    mean = mean(persons)
    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(length):
        total_sum += (persons[i]-mean)**2
    square_root = total_sum*1.0/length
    return math.sqrt(square_root)
```

This is the assignment:
Write a class called Person that has two data members - the person's name and age. It should have an init method that takes two values and uses them to initialize the data members.

Write a separate function (not part of the Person class) called std_dev that takes as a parameter a list of Person objects and returns the standard deviation of all their ages (the population standard deviation that uses a denominator of N, not the sample standard deviation, which uses a different denominator).

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: how do I format code?

Comment: Code formatting with markdown: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
persons=Person
```

Within this line, you're replacing the persons parameter values with the type Person. First, remove this line.

Another thing you need to do to fix your situation is, you're trying to sum persons, itself, I think what you meant there is to sum each person's age, to get all ages of all persons you can do:

```
persons_age = [person.age for person in persons]
```

now you can sum(persons_age).

From that, you can follow on, and fix the rest of the assignment

Comment: Now that I have the full code, I could help him better, thanks anyway!

Comment: I fixed that code, but now I'm getting this error: Test Failed: 'float' object is not callable. My code is: import math

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def std_dev(persons):
    persons_age = [person.age for person in persons]
    mean = (sum(persons_age) * 1.0)/len(persons)
    length = len(persons)
    mean = mean(persons)
    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(length):
        total_sum += (persons_age[i]-mean)**2
    square_root = (total_sum * 1.0)/length
    return math.sqrt(square_root)

Comment: @codallion dude, next time, edit it into the question. Also, the stack-trace should also be telling you exactly what row is causing the problem. Running your code, the following line is what's wrong: `mean = mean(persons)`. You have already created the `mean` variable before. Just remove the line line i wrote above, and it shouldn't crash anymore.